# WebAudio LFO: shift range from {-1, 1} to {0, 1}

Tags: web-audio-api

Every tutorial on WebAudio LFOs creates an Oscillator for the LFO which is then routed to the `gain` parameter of a Gain node.

But AFAIK oscillators produce output from -1 to 1 so for half the cycle we are sending a negative value to the gain multiplier. At best this is clipped to a minimum gain of 0 at worst it goes into the negative effectively doubling up the frequency of the modulating wave.

How do you set up a simple LFO then that oscillates from 0 to 1 at the expected frequency?

Comment: There's a method here for doing it with two oscillators:  http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/JavaScript.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioNode/connect(AudioParam).html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine an OscillatorNode with a ConstantSourceNode to achieve the desired effect.

```
const oscillatorNode = new OscillatorNode(context);
const constantSourceNode = new ConstantSourceNode(context);
const gainNode = new GainNode(context, { gain: 0.5 });

oscillatorNode.connect(gainNode);
constantSourceNode.connect(gainNode);

gainNode.connect(context.destination);

oscillatorNode.start();
constantSourceNode.start();
```

As you said the OscillatorNode will oscillate between -1 and 1. The ConstantSourceNode outputs a constant signal with the value 1. If we combine these two nodes we get a signal oscillating between 0 and 2. We can then use a GainNode to divide that signal by 2. The result will be a signal oscillating between 0 and 1.

Comment: Nice one. The 2 Osc method that @Brad mentions is also good, but the ConstantSource is more versatile: I've modified your approach to have the CS Node output -1.0, this having an LFO that subtracts rather than adds from the Oscillator's Gain node, thus preventing clipping.